# Regex in PHP returning preg_match(): Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N{name}, \U, or \u

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm trying to check for user input validity in PHP using regex, but I just can't figure out what's. wrong with my regex

Here's my `if` statement:

```
if(is_numeric($_SESSION['l-teacher'])&&preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\u0590-\u05ff\*\-\.\, ]+$/',$_POST['content'])&&preg_match('/^[\u0590-\u05fe ]+$/',$_POST['name'])&&is_numeric($_POST['stars'])&&$_POST['stars']>0&&$_POST['stars']<6){
```

\ if true
}

I'm getting the following error:

> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N{name}, \U, or \u at offset 12

Comment: Maybe it should be `^[A-Za-z0-9\x{0590}-\x{05ff}*., -]+$`

Comment: Still not working for me unfortunately.

Comment: Same error, no results, other?

Comment: @user3783243 Please avoid posting potential answers as comments; it breaks the voting and editing features of the site, and makes things less obvious to later readers.

Comment: @IMSoP It's not an answer, I have no strings to test with. That was my guess.

Comment: @user3783243 I realise it's not a "full" answer, but if it had been a correct guess, or the resulting conversation had led to a solution, what would have happened next? The OP cannot accept it as a correct answer, and you can't edit it to include more details, so we end up with a "solved" question that has no answers posted to it. I understand the temptation, but it's best to either expand such a comment into a short answer, or wait for someone who's more certain to come along.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

"PCRE" stands for "Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions", but that doesn't mean that all features available in Perl5 regexes are available in PCRE. The PHP manual has a page on [PCRE: Differences from Perl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.differences.php), which includes a similar statement to the one in the error message:

> The following Perl escape sequences are not supported: \l, \u, \L, \U. In fact these are implemented by Perl's general string-handling and are not part of its pattern matching engine.

PHP (since 7.0) does have [support for `\u` escapes in a string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double), *if it is double quoted*, so `"\u{0590}"` would represent that character *but might not have the desired effect inside the regex*, since you need to tell the character class somehow that you want a range of Unicode code points, not a set of possible 8-bit values.

What you actually want in this case is *the PCRE notation for Unicode codepoints*, which is described under [Escape Sequences](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php):

> In UTF-8 mode, "\x{...}" is allowed, where the contents of the braces is a string of hexadecimal digits. It is interpreted as a UTF-8 character whose code number is the given hexadecimal number.

The mention of "UTF-8 mode" refers to [the `u` pattern modifier](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

> This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is incompatible with Perl. Pattern and subject strings are treated as UTF-8. An invalid subject will cause the preg_* function to match nothing; an invalid pattern will trigger an error of level E_WARNING.

So I believe your pattern of:

```
'/^[\u0590-\u05fe ]+$/'
```

should be changed to:

```
'/^[\x{0590}-\x{05fe} ]+$/u'
```

Note that as the manual for the `u` modifier implies, the subject string *must be encoded as UTF-8* for this to work; there is no support for UTF-16 or any other Unicode encoding.